# Ошибка построения решения в MSVC++ 2010

Tags: winapi, c++

При сборке данного проекта (Win32):

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND hwnd,
                                UINT msg,
                                WPARAM wparam,
                                LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return(0);
        }   break;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam));
}

int WINAPI WinMai(HINSTANCE hinstance,
                  HINSTANCE hprevinstance,
                  LPSTR lpcmdline,
                  int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX windowsclass;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    windowsclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowsclass.style = CS_DBLCLKS|CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    windowsclass.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProc;
    windowsclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowsclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowsclass.hInstance = hinstance;
    windowsclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowsclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowsclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    windowsclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowsclass.lpszClassName = _T("WINDOWSCLASS");
    windowsclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&windowsclass))
        return 0;

    if(!(hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, 
                               _T("WINDOWSCLASS"), 
                               _T("Базовое окно"),
                               WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                               0, 0,
                               500, 400,
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               hinstance,
                               NULL)))
        return(0);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return(msg.wParam);
}
```

Вывело ошибку:

> `MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WinMain@16 в функции ___tmainCRTStartup
> fatal error LNK1120: 1 неразрешенных внешних элементов`

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты забыл букву n в названии главной функции) WinMai исправь на WinMain